# Adding abline to legend in barplot RStudio

Tags: r

```
barplot(counts, main="title",
      xlab=group, col=rainbow(20),
      legend = rownames(counts), 
      beside=TRUE, xlim=c(1,30))
abline(v=mean(df$ddd), col="red", lwd=2.5)
```

My question is - how to add abline to the legend? I have tried to throw the legend from barplot area and do something but it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without know more about your data it's difficult to replicate exactly what you're looking for, but I think you might find R's ggplot2 package useful:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data=iris) + geom_bar(aes(x=iris$Sepal.Length,fill=iris$Species)) +
      #Add abline - specifiy color aes so it appears in the legend
      geom_abline(aes(intercept=0,slope=1,color="Line description"),size=2.5,show_guide=TRUE) + 

      #Override the lines that would appear in "fill" portion of legend - the part of the legend that refers to species
      guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = 0), title="[TITLE OF FILL]"), 
             color = guide_legend(title="[TITLE OF LINE]")) + 

      #Change color of line to what you actually want
      scale_color_manual(values="#CC6666")
```

We basically "trick" ggplot into putting the geom_abline in the legend and then from there we can change the title, description, and color of the line.

The above code gives us:

[image]